# Dynamic Grid Layout with Vertical Stacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm aware that various jquery plugins exist that allow for creating dynamic grid layouts, but I can't seem to utilize any of them to create automatically sorted grids that FILL A SINGLE COLUMN before continuing to the next

What I wish to achieve (blocks numbered):

```
_____________
|_1_| 3 |_5_|
| 2 |___|_6_|
|___|_4_|_7_|
```

EDIT TO ADD DETAIL: I wish to stack fill vertically instead of horizontally for content. Most systems would put 2 where I have put 3 in the above example.

EDIT 2: Each of the blocks represented by number can have variable heights (based on contents), and I would like it to assign a column to each number that would get the entire columns height to be approximately equal (or as close as possible) to the other columns

Comment: Are you saying you want the equivalent of table colspans, or is the ordering the only thing that matters and contents of cell 2 and 3 are just *more* compared to 1, 4-7? If not the latter, are you sure you don't want to just put it in a table (I'm having trouble finding the design reason for this)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe isotope can do this using its fitColumn and cellsByColumn layout modes.

See demo: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/layout-modes.html

Comment: Would it be possible to have it the horizontal layouts react to browser width instead of height?

Comment: Not by default. But you can use other scripts to determine browser width, and then run isotope with the width.

Answer (score 0):

[Bootstrap's CSS Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) can do this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>1</p>
        <p>2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>3</p>
        <p>4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>5</p>
        <p>6</p>
        <p>7</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that "rows" may not directly align depending on the arbitrary content length of each `<p>` in the `col-md-4`s. Also `<p>`s aren't required, you can put whatever you want in there.

Comment: What if you do not know the amount of contents in each <p>? If the contents are variable, are you able to have it assign the numbers to columns so that each is about equal in height (would likely require javascript)?

Comment: @Tom http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/layout-modes.html see `masonryHorizontal`, `fitColumns` and `cellsByColumn`.